# IF-ELSEIF chain to Hashmap logic

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a bonus that depend on the amount of user in an arrayList.

And my idea to make it more flexible is an Hashmap

But i'm looking for some idea to make it work.

```
int amountWin = 0;
if(participants.size() >= 10){
    amountWin += 100;
} else if(participants.size() >= 5){
    amountWin += 50;
}
```

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> bonus = new HashMap<>();
bonus.put(10, 100);
bonus.put(5, 50);
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: To make it work with the hashmap. To delete this if else if chain because i want to make it flexible with file

Comment: You'll have to provide more information (see [mcve]). You have a `List` called `participants`, right? And if the list has more than 10 participants, you want to add 100 to `amountWin`? If so, I'm not sure you need the `Map` as there's nothing inherently wrong with an `if...else if` statement.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just i want to make it FLEXIBLE. I want to make it with file like json

Comment: For anything like this to work, you're probably going to need an ordered map such as `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```java
HashMap<Integer, Integer> participantsByBonus = new HashMap<>();
participantsByBonus.put(10, 100);
participantsByBonus.put(5, 50);

int amountWin = 0;
int bonus = participantsByBonus.keySet().stream()
                               .filter(participants -> participants >= participants.size)
                               .min(Integer::compareTo)
                               .map(participantsByBonus::get)
                               .orElse(0);

amountWin += bonus;
```

`filter(participants -> participants >= participants.size())` looks for all `keys` that are greater than the amount of the `participants` and `min()` will pick the minimum.

If the amount of participants is to low you will get no bonus (`orElse(0)`).

Comment: This won't work with an unordered map, and with a `NavigableMap` it can be avoided entirely with `floorEntry`.

Comment: Thanks, so no need of NavigableMap?

Comment: @MagOuille `NavigableMap` would be much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary `Map` does not provide any sorting guarantees. For a query like this, a `NavigableMap` such as `TreeMap` will do exactly what you need.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> bonuses = new TreeMap<>();
bonuses.put(10, 100);
bonuses.put(5, 50);

int prizeAmount = 0;
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> bonus = bonuses.floorEntry(participants.size());
if (bonus != null) {
    prizeAmount += bonus.getValue();
}
```